# How do i connect UILabel to applicationSignificantTimeChange

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to connect a UILabel to change at midnight 12am using this code

-(void)applicationSignificantTimeChange: (UIApplication *)app;

anyone help me in putting it into my app so that it works?

Comment: You are going to have to explain your goal a *lot* more clearly than you have. If you don't take the time to write a clear question, it's unlikely anyone will take the time to try and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement this function in your application delegate.  Implement a method in your view controller that you call when applicationSignificantTimeChange is invoked.  Inside that view controller method is where you'd request the system time and change your label as appropriate.